# How to modify contact form

Tags: forms, webforms

I'm trying to modify the contact form to add a privacy clause before the "Send" button, I have to add a text and two mandatory check boxes. But I just started with and I have not much idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Drupal/Webdform are you using?

Comment: Im using Drupal 7.63 actually

Answer (score 0):

You can go to `/admin/structure/webform` and then click `Build` on the form you are using as a contact form.

Then you can click `Add element` and add your checkboxes or any other field you need.

The option to make the checkboxes mandatory will be under `Form validation`.

Comment: I'm using Contact form actually.  Should i download and install Webform? thanks

Comment: There is no option you _should_ go for. The answer is for webform since your question is tagged. You can of course use any other suitable module.